# How Can I Comprehensively Manage my VBA UserForm's Properties?

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I am writing my first VBA Add-In under *Microsoft Office Word 2007* with *Windows 7 Pro/64*.  Part of this Add-In is a *UserForm*.  Using the Visual Basic editor that runs from *Word*, I find there are two ways of viewing, and two ways of modifying a UserForm's properties:

1. View all properties from *Object Browser* (<kbd>F2</kbd>)
2. View ***some*** properties and edit them from *Properties Window* (<kbd>F4</kbd>)
3. Manually enter and edit any property from the *Code* window (<kbd>F7</kbd>)

Here is a screenshot of my Properties and Code windows:

[image: Visual Basic Editor]

A problem I find is that ***the Properties Window contains only a subset*** of the UserForm's properties (notice that `CanPaste`, `CanRedo`, and `CanUndo` don't appear in *Properties*), and ***changes made in the Properties Window are overridden*** by changes made in the Code window (e.g., at runtime, `Me.Caption` from the *Code* window above overrides the `Caption` field in *Properties*).

I suppose I should avoid using *Properties* at all then, and enter all settings via `UserForm_Initialize` as shown above.  But (a) for some settings, *Properties* makes several settings at once.  For example, selecting Verdana Bold from *Properties* equals `Font = Verdana` and `Font.Bold = True` in *Code*.  And (b) it seems *Properties* sets the subset of properties it controls to defaults of its choosing, and if I change them I can't see what they started out as.

I therefore desire unified and comprehensive access to all my UserForm's properties at once, including the aforementioned default settings.  Does anyone know how to reveal a UserForm's default settings as code, or to automatically open **all** its current settings in the Code window?  Is there an umbrella mechanism I'm not aware of?

I'm not a veteran VBA programmer, but I can't believe my experience is unique.  I've searched the 'net in vain for a solution.  How do you with more experience manage this dilemma?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the Properties window to set **appearance**-related properties at **design time**. Those property values will then always apply *unless* you explicitly change them at run-time with VBA code.

Properties that don't relate to appearance, such as `CanPaste` and `CanRedo` relate to the **state** of the form at **run-time**, so it doesn't make sense to have them configurable at design-time.

You can change nearly all of the properties at run-time, whether it is in the `Initialize` event or elsewhere. You can even add controls at run-time, but your changes won't be persisted once the instance of the form terminates.

Comment: I do appreciate your answer, and it has helped me manage my form's properties.  But some properties such as `Enabled, DrawBuffer, Cycle,` and `KeepScrollBarsVisible` are present in the Properties window but don't seem to be strictly appearance-related as you say.  And other properties that do seem to be appearance-related  such as `VerticalScrollbarSide` are missing from the Properties window.  Nonetheless, I take the silence (so far) about better solutions to mean that there are none.  I'll wait a few more days and if there are no other answers will accept this as SO's consensus.